# CALayer appears only for one second, then disappears

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I'm adding CALayer to top and bottom of scrollable objects (UIScrollView, TableView, CollectionView) to display them when there is a content behind the visible area.

```
class TableViewWithCALayers: UITableView {

var topGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?
var bottomGradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    guard self.topGradientLayer != nil && self.bottomGradientLayer != nil else {
        addGradientLayerToTop() // create layer, set frame, etc.
        addGradientLayerToBottom()
        return
    }

//        addGradientLayerToTop()// if uncomment it - multiple layers are created and they are visible, but this is not the solution...
        handleLayerAppearanceAfterLayoutSubviews() // playing with opacity here
    }
```

How I create layer:

```
func addGradientLayerToTop() {
    if let superview = superview {
        self.topGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        let colorTop =  UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        if let topLayer = self.topGradientLayer {
            topLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
            topLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
            topLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: self.frame.origin, size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, self.layerHeight))
            superview.layer.insertSublayer(topLayer, above: self.layer)
            if (self.contentOffset.y == 0) {
                //                if we are at the top - hide layer
                // topLayer.opacity = 0.0 //temporarily disabled, so it is 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TableViewWithCALayers** works nice everywhere, except using TableView with xib files:

```
class XibFilesViewController : CustomUIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: TableViewWithCALayers!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
    self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = false // this line doesn't help...
}
```

**CustomUIViewController** is used in many other ViewControllers where **TableViewWithCALayers** works good, so it should not create a problem.
Layers at the top and bottom appear for one second, then disappear. Logs from **LayoutSubviews()** func say that they are visible and opacity are 1.0, but something covers them. What can it be and how to deal with that?

Any help is appreciated!)

```
topLayer.zPosition = 10000 //doesn't help
topLayer.masksToBounds = false //doesn't help as well
```

Answer (score 1):

When using nib files it's good practice, and design to add the UIView that you want to draw the layer on into your prototype cell, or header/footed and then have that view confirm to your class that's actually handling the layer.